# Is there a way to lookup refcount for a kobject?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I expected to find a function along the lines of `kobject_check_refcount`, that returned the current refcount without altering it, in [kobject.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9-rc3/source/lib/kobject.c), but as far as I can see there isn't one. Is there such a function existing in the kernel source somewhere? I can see it being useful for debugging purposes at points.

Edit: found [kref_read](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9-rc3/source/include/linux/kref.h#L34) which sounds like it fits the bill. Just testing to see if it works as I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, looks like [kref_read](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9-rc3/source/include/linux/kref.h#L34) is the right way to go.

```c
static inline unsigned int kref_read(const struct kref *kref)
{
    return refcount_read(&kref->refcount);
}
```